# Posting on my Facebook page using Facebook graph api Not showing in public

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook page. I created a Python module for posting in Facebook page using access_token and Page ID . Once I Posted I can see the Post in my facebook page. But that Post i am not able to see from public( For example, For other people, when they check mypage , they are  not able to see the posted contents using my App, Other posts am able to see ) . My intention is to create an App for myself ( not Public ) , From that app I need to post in my facebook pages. What could be the reason . Do we need any specific approval for the app even though , it is for my personal use .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posts made with the API only show up if the App is public/live. It does not matter if it is for personal use only.

Comment: So I cannot creat a desktop app for this. Is that right @luschn

Comment: sure you can, but the app needs to be public. check your facebook app settings.